# How to close the collapse menu automatically when I click on "Search"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drupal, drupal-navigation

I created a file collapse.js in the theme of my site. It works very well.

On this page :

https://www.s1biose.com/article

When I open the menu on the right and click on the "Rechercher" action button, the collapse menu remains open.

How do I close the collapse menu automatically when I click on the "Rechercher" button ?

The file already contains some rules.

```
(function ($) {

  $('#navbar-collapse-first').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
       $('#navbar-collapse-second').collapse('hide');
  })

  $('#navbar-collapse-second').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
       $('#navbar-collapse-first').collapse('hide');
  })

  $('#navbar-collapse-first').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
       $('body').addClass('overlay-is-navbar-collapse');
  });

  $('#navbar-collapse-first').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
       $('body').removeClass('overlay-is-navbar-collapse');
  });

  $('#navbar-collapse-second').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
       $('body').addClass('overlay-is-navbar-collapse');
  });

  $('#navbar-collapse-second').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
       $('body').removeClass('overlay-is-navbar-collapse');
  });

})(window.jQuery);
```

[image]

```
<div data-drupal-selector="edit-actions" class="form-actions form-group js-form-wrapper form-wrapper" id="edit-actions">
```

Rechercher

Comment: "Rechercher" action button not on right. I'm seeing it on left side. Or you can add class to "Rechercher" button and hide it using jquery.

Comment: @RamRatanBairar Yes it's the right menu, I added a screenshot in my question. I want when the button is clicked, the collapse menu closes automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $('#rechercher').on('click', function () {
       $('#navbar-collapse-second').removeClass('in');
  });
```

add id rechercher to your button

Comment: How to indicate that the menu is hidden only with '.form-submit' of '#navbar-collapse-second' ? Currently if I click on gggg anywhere on the site, the right menu closes. I want it only if I click on '.form-submit' in the right menu.

Comment: give id to form-submit and click on that to trigger above code.